# Child propagation to parent from object of objects

Tags: vue.js, quasar-framework

I have a table with column dropdowns and instead of creating objects for each (ie data: {col1: {},..}), I have a object of objects that is initialized and populated on "created".

Thus, the issue I'm having is, the child components are not properly propagating changes to the parent component when the object being passed to the child prop is an object from an object of objects.

FYI the tableData is retrieved via axios.
I'm using quasar and vue.

I've initially had a single object being passed to the child components and was able to have sync modifier working properly. Then moved on to making an object of objects and passing to each column.

console.log(this.selected) in the child component selectionList is printing empty.

NOTE: this is an example that contains the root issue.

table.vue #parent

```
<q-table
  row-key="id"
 :tableData
 :columns
 :visible-columns="visibleColumns">
 <q-tr slot="top-row" slot-scope="props">
  <q-td v-for="col in visibleColumns">
   <child-component 
    :selected.sync="dropDownSelected[col]"
    :options="dropDownOptions[col]"
     />
  </q-td>
 </q-tr>
</q-table>

<script>
import ChildComponent from 'path/to/child-component.vue';
export default{
 name: 'table',
 components: {
  'child-component': ChildComponent
 },
 data(){
  return{
    tableData: [{id: 1, col1: 'a', col2: 'b', col3: 'c'}],
    columns: [
     {name: 'col1', label: 'Col1', field: 'col1'},
     {name: 'col2', label: 'Col2', field: 'col2'},
     {name: 'col3', label: 'Col3', field: 'col3'},
    ],
    visibleColumns: ['col1', 'col2'],
    dropDownSelected: {},
    dropDownOptions: {}
  }
 },
 created() {
  this.initializeDropDown();
  this.populateTableSelect();
 },
 methods: {
  initializeDropDown(){
   for(var col in this.columns){
    this.dropDownSelected[col.name] = [];
    this.dropDownOptions[col.name] = [];
   }
  },
  populateTableSelect(){
    // initiallize all columns with new Set
    var tmp_set = {};
    for(var col in this.dropDownOptions){
     tmp_set[col] = new Set();
    }
    // iterate row, add items to set
    for(var row = 0; row < this.tableData.length; row++){
     for(var col in this.dropDownOptions){
      tmp_set[col].add(this.tableData[row][col]);
     }
    }
    for (var col in this.dropDownOptions) {
     tmp_set[col] = [...tmp_set[col]];
     tmp_set[col].sort();
     tmp_set[col] = tmp_set[col].map(item => ({ label: item, value: item }));
     tmp_set[col].unshift({ label: 'Select All', value: 'Select All' });
     this.dropDownOptions[col] = tmp_set[col];
    }
  }
 },
}
</script>
```

child-component.vue

```
<q-select
 multiple
 :options="options"
 :value="selected"
 @input="selectionList">
</q-select>

<script>
export default{
 name: 'child-component',
 props: {
  options: {type: Array, required: true},
  selected: {type: Array, default: () => ([])},
  allValue: { type: String, default: 'Select All' }
 },
 methods: {
  selectionList(inputList){
    // logic below used from outside source
    if (inputList.find(item => item === this.allValue)){
     if(this.selected.find(item => item === this.allValue)){
      // case 1: one item is unchecked while 'all' is checked -> unchecks 'all' + keep other
      inputList.splice(inputList.indexOf(this.allValue), 1);
      this.$emit('update:selected', inputList);
     }
     else {
      // case 2: 'all' is checked -> select-all
      this.$emit('update:selected', this.options.map(option => option.value));
     }
    }
    else {
     if(this.selected.find(item => item === this.allValue)){
     // case 3: unchecking 'all' -> clear selected
      this.$emit('update:selected', []);
     }
     else{
      if(inputList.length === this.options.length -1){
       // case 4: len is equal to options -> select-all
       this.$emit('update:selected', this.options.map(option => option.value));
      }
      else {
       // case 5: check an item
       this.$emit('update:selected', inputList);
      }
     }
    }
   },
 },
}
</script>
```

I expected passing an object from an object of objects would've allowed 'Select All' logic to propagate to the parent.

I see no errors coming so I have no clue as to what js is doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I see, this is a simple reactivity problem explained in the [documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Change-Detection-Caveats).
`dropDownOptions` and `dropDownSelected` are objects on which you add new keys. Every time you do that, you need to call `this.$set`.

I think if you only change this method you should be good:

```js
initializeDropDown(){
  for(var col in this.columns){
    this.$set(this.dropDownSelected, col.name, []);
    this.$set(this.dropDownOptions, col.name, []);
  }
},
```

Comment: Ah dang this caveat always gets me. Thanks friend.